# Ionic CSS is not loading when page is refreshed

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, styles

In my ionic app everything looks perfect when the application is first opened. But if i refresh the page css is not loading and the page looks bad. This is only apparent on the iPhone's look of Chrome. And problem persists until i restart the application with the ionic-serve command. But if I open up a new incognito tab, everything seems right.

What is the problem?

This is first looking:

[image]

This is second looking:

[image]

And this is my scss code:

```
page-home {
.ion-header {font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color:#BBBF95; font-size: 18px !important;font-weight: bold !important;}
.ion-content-preview {color:white !important;font-style: italic;}
.item-content {
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
  .item-md {
    background: transparent !important;
} 
ion-toolbar {
    min-height: 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
}
.page-count{
    float:right !important;
    margin-right: 14px !important;
    color:white !important;
    min-height: 10px !important;
    height: 10px !important;
    margin-top: 3px !important;
}
.item-checkbox {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 3px;
  }
  .item-checkbox .checkbox {
    right: auto;
    color:white !important;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif !important;
  }
ion-select{
    float:right !important;
    margin-top: -30px !important;
}
```

}

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initially loading the 'app', at browser launch, your developer tools aren't active. Ionic selects an 'theme' based on your device. If you inspect your page you'll see that the  gets the 'md' with 'platform-core' classs (and some more stuff) at startup. When using the developer tools with the **device mode** enabled and you refresh at that point, the app reloads and the class is set again based on your 'selected device'. In your case iPhone 6/7/8. You'll now have e.g. 'ios' and 'platform-ios' and more set. This is giving you that 'css error'.

This is not an error btw. You'll just have to implement some platform specific css tweaks. That will fix your problem.

Try using:

```
ionic serve --lab
```

You'll be able to view multiple platforms and it's styles. This way you'll be able to inspect them easily and create platform specific css tweaks easier.

Device mode:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

Comment: I solved problem with your idea. I added .item-ios { background: transparent; } and everything work well. Thank you for your help.